how connect MySQL,Railway and Vercel
I want to connect my web application with a MySQL database hosted on Railway. It works locally, but when I deploy the application in Vercel, it no longer takes anything from the database. Is there a problem with the API URL? The local one works fine for me.
I need it to work and be able to get the data from the database. If it works locally, I don't know why it doesn't work in Vercel. The environment variables are correct.

Please read How to ask, Do ask yourself what the reader on stackoverflow can we do with "The environment variables are correct" and "Is there a problem with the API URL?" (without going into assumptions...)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
